# Using gh-ost for column drop with Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-migration

We're using [GitHub gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost) for online migrations in our Rails application. The objective is to de-couple migrations from application code changes and also to avoid requiring downtime for larger migrations that cannot simply be run via Rake tasks without impacting site performance.

This fine, with one exception: dropping columns. When we drop a column, Rails gets confused and starts throwing exceptions. The reason is the [Rails schema cache](http://kirshatrov.com/2016/12/13/schema-cache/). Even when the application code is not referencing the column (a process requirement we have imposed that must be satisfied before running the gh-ost migration) Rails still thinks it's there. So it's default behaviour of using `SELECT *` on a table causes it to try to get data from columns that (after the DB migration is complete) no longer exist.

We're trying to come up with a solution to this problem that still allows us to meet the two objectives mentioned above. Two possibilities are (1) restarting the Rails server after the gh-ost migration is complete or (2) clearing the Rails schema cache after the gh-ost migration is complete. Both of these are feasible, though they limit our ability to *completely* decouple the online migration from application code changes, and both have the potential to impact site performance.

Another option which, given the size of our database & application I don't think we are willing to consider, is turning off Rails schema caching.

Has anyone else addressed this problem? What are our options?

Comment: I wonder if you could `rake db:schema:cache:dump` (and possibly edit the result) to get the schema without the column that is going away and then use that in place of Rails digging the schema out of the database. Seems to work in the console with `SomeModel.column_names` and the like. No idea what would happen in real life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the GitHub [issues page for gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost/issues/579), and learned a few ways to deal with this challenge:

For Rails 4, override `ActiveRecord::Base.columns` to remove the column from the array of columns for the model in question:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.columns
    super.reject {|column| column.name == 'employee_email'}
  end
end
```

In Rails 5, this can be done using `.ignored_columns`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.ignored_columns = %w(employee_email)
end
```

Credit to [this blog post](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/24/rails-5-adds-active-record-ignored-columns.html) for the code samples.

An alternative is to remove the "eager loading" from the relevant association, so that the Rails schema cache does not interfere as described in my question.

Regardless of the option chosen, it has to be deployed to the Rails application *ahead* of performing the gh-ost migration. This ensures the application will function regardless of whether the column is present or not, removing the need to restart the Rails application after a gh-ost migration cut-over.